# Linux module loadables

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I am trying to accomplish following:
There is a binary file with simple mathematics (+ and *) - like a library.  And the plans are to create such file in assembly.  The question is how to "give" contents of such file to the module?

I was hoping that ELF has required functionality but than module is ELF and it is not clear whether it is possible to load and use ELF object inside a module.

Comment: You want to make a kernel module that itself loads its own modules? Why?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are saying correctly, you have a piece of code in assembly containing some functions that do basic mathematics and you'd like to use them in a linux kernel module?

Compile the assembly together with the kernel module i.e. add the asmoutput.o file to the dependencies for the kernel module. However, given that this would make your module platform dependent I've no idea what the procedure is. I don't think it's commonly done; most kernel modules are in C.

You're misunderstanding what ELF is I think. ELF is the format of the binary file used for executables, nothing more.

If you're looking to load other kernel modules, well, module dependency happens so this is definitely possible, but as Rup says in the comments, why? There are very few reasons for switching out various dependent bits of code.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't add that the goal is to have that object with mathematics be replaceable.

Comment: So, a plugin system for a plugin system? If you want the mathematics to be replaced I'd recommend rebuilding the kernel module with the appropriate maths in it. I'd still question why this needs to be done in kernel space.

Comment: I can try to accomplish my task by having all the possible ways of communication and choose the one that suits best.  I know of 3 ways if getting information to kernel space: device, procfs and reading file from fs. Is there any other way?

Comment: I couldn't get the purpose of replacing the mathematics. What I would try to guess is, you have perhaps multiple algorithms for doing the same task and you want your kernel module to use the algorithm that you want. For this you want to patch in and patch out your algorithm from the kernel. A simpler way would be to compile all the possible algorithms as separate functions, and make a /sys entry for which algorithm has to be used. You can update that entry to cause kernel to switch to the algorithm you want. If you are debugging a mathematical algorithm,then you should better do it in userland

Comment: and may be you can have a look at netlink sockets also.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for hints.  I think that the rest work is up for me.  Thank you all.